# Why is $P(x\in A_t)=\sup_\eta|P(\eta_x\cap A_t=\emptyset)-P(\eta\cap A_t=\emptyset)|$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $S$ be some non-empty set, $\{0,1\}$ a set with two elements and $E:=\{0,1\}^S$ the set of all functions from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$. Given $\eta\in E$ and $x\in S$, $\eta_x\in E$ is defined to be equal to $\eta$ everywhere except on $x$. Finally let $(\Omega,F,P,A)$ be a process with values in $E$ and note that the function
\begin{equation*}
    E\ni\eta\mapsto\{x\in S:\eta(x)=1\}
\end{equation*}
allows us to identify $E$ with the power set of $S$.

As far as I understand, Liggett is using the fact that
$$\forall t\geq 0:P(x\in A_t)=\sup_{\eta\in E}|P(\eta_x\cap A_t=\emptyset)-P(\eta\cap A_t=\emptyset)|$$
on page $163$
of his [Continuous Time Markov Processes](https://doi.org/10.1090/gsm/113). I have no idea how to prove this, can someone help please?

Comment: You seem to have the notation for your construction of the set $E$ backwards. The set $S^{ \{0,1 \}}$ denotes the set of functions from $ \{ 0,1 \}$ to $S$ (not the other way around as you've stated in the question)

Comment: @FD_bfa Indeed, thank you for the remark!

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer on what the exact problem is? In what context does Liggett use that result (for those without a copy of the book)?

Comment: @FD_bfa "In what context does Liggett use that result" - Liggett uses this equation to proof the following fact (actually something stronger): If we consider the contact process on an infinite lattice, but with finite initial states (i.e. only finitely many sites are infected), then the number of infected sites remains finite.